# STRING_split performance Issue

Tags: t-sql, split, sql-server-2016

I have two queries which split comma separated list into rows and insert into table variable.

For first query I have used custom function which is:

USER defined Function for Spilt.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split_S]
(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(MAX)
   ,@sDelimiter VARCHAR(8)      
) 
RETURNS @List TABLE ([item] VARCHAR(8000)) 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(MAX) 
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1)))
        ,@sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

    IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
        INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
    END

    IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
        INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList-- Put the last item in
RETURN 
END
```

Query 1 :

```
 DECLARE @F TABLE(F BIGINT) 
INSERT INTO @F
SELECT [item] FROM [dbo].[Split_S] 
(N'82,13,51,68,6',',')
```

Query 2 :

```
DECLARE @F2 TABLE(F BIGINT) 
INSERT INTO @F2
SELECT Value 
from  
STRING_SPLIT(N'82,13,51,68,6',',')
```

Query Plan of Both Query

[image: Query Plan of Both Query]

Why 37% and using STRING_SPLIT Its 63% .
but if i only compare select statement then query cost of STRING_SPLIT is 1%.

Which query has better performance and why?

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: ITS T- SQL 2016

Answer (score 0):

If you will check only the part of the query that include the select query, then you will get that using STRING_SPLIT gives much better performance according too execution plan (EP). the result will be 99% vs 1%.

But when we use the data that returned by the STRING_SPLIT function (for example "select... into" or like in your case "insert...select'), then you might notice that the server uses "**table spool (Eager Spool)**" which make the difference. This operator takes the rows and stores them in a hidden temporary object stored in the tempdb database (the idea of using this logic is that  the spooled data can be reused later in the execution plan). The "eager" spool takes **ALL** rows from the previously operator at one time, which means that this is "**blocking operator**".

Comment: By the way, If you will SET STATISTICS IO ON, then you will see the differences ;-)